# 'mo' and 'demo' pronunciation research

Tags: particles, pronunciation, pitch-accent

I am looking for a native speaker who could answer the following question:

Is there any difference in pronunciation of the morpheme 'mo' in the following words (are there any differences in tone)?

- だれも (as in 部屋の中には**誰も**いませんでした)
- だれも (as in **誰も**が名文を書けるわけではない)
- だれでも (as in 来る人は**誰でも**歓迎されます)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a difference.

- 部屋の中には[だれも]{LHH}いませんでした。
- [だれもが]{HLLL}名文を書けるわけではない。
- 来る人は[だれでも]{HLLL}歓迎されます。 ([だれでも]{LHHH} is also fine, maybe younger speakers prefer this?)

You can [try Google Translate's voice synthesizer](https://translate.google.co.jp/#ja/en/%E9%83%A8%E5%B1%8B%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E8%AA%B0%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82%0A%E8%AA%B0%E3%82%82%E3%81%8C%E5%90%8D%E6%96%87%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%80%82%0A%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AF%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E6%AD%93%E8%BF%8E%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82) (click the speaker button). I confirmed the result was fairly good at least in terms of pitch accent, although the English translation is flawed.

I don't know if there is a generic rule which you can apply to other interrogatives. If there is any, I think non-native speakers are better at such rules :)

Comment: Thank you. What about just the 'mo' part. How would you describe the tone of 'mo' (rising, falling etc.) in negative senteces, positive sentences (with universal, i.e. 'every-' meaning) and when used as a part of 'demo'?